# How to make this validation work with required?

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, validation

I'm trying to make some validation inside my app, but i'm not sure why i can't make it to work properly. I just want so show user info "email is required", when he hits a e-mail input and left empty (even, when se make some changes), and info about "email is invalid" when don't match mine pattern.

I tried a lot of combinations but i'm not sure which is best, thats why i decided to make it simple at start. Maybe somebody has better implementation of that?

Component:

```
  public accountForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private router: Router, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { 
   }

   get formControls() { return this.accountForm.controls; }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.accountForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: [
        null,
        [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$')
        ]
      ]
    });
  }

..
```

Html:

```
...
    <form novalidate [formGroup]="accountForm">
      <div class="input-group mb-3 flex-nowrap">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="email" formControlName="email">
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="formControls.email.required" class="input-error">Email is required</div>
      <div *ngIf="formControls.email.invalid && formControls.email.touched" class="input-error">Email is invalid</div>
...
```

At this moment only validation with pattern is working, can't make to work require.

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz for your problem?

Comment: Can you just use a native HTML `required` attribute on your `<input>` element? E.g. like the first example in this Angular docs page: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Comment: @Collierre, if use ReactiveForm, it's not necesary "required" (is a kind of mix between Reactive and Template Form)

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the built in email validator rhather than going for a custom pattern.

You need to refer to the email control as

```
accountForm.get('email').errors?.email
```

and not directly by referring to the `FormControl` as you are instantiating the `FormGroup` instance in your controller class and you should try to find your controller in that

Full working example at: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-form-email-validator